# Escaped closure capture strong links or not?

Tags: swift, swift3, escaping, closures

In my example I create instance inside other function. By the end of function, I expect that instance2 should be are nil and completionHandlers array should't have strong link to SomeClass2 but completionHandlers have are still link on.

That looks like @escaping closure create strong links on self inside.

```
var completionHandlers: [() -> Void] = []

func someFunctionWithEscapingClosure(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandlers.append(completionHandler)
}

class SomeClass {
    var x = 10
    func doSomething() {
        let instance2 = SomeClass2()
        instance2.doSomething2()
    }
}

class SomeClass2 {
    var x = 11
    func doSomething2() {
        someFunctionWithEscapingClosure {
            // still exist
            self.x = 77
        }
    }
}

let instance = SomeClass()
instance.doSomething()

completionHandlers.first!()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94):

> If you assign a closure to a property of a class instance, and the closure captures that instance by referring to the instance or its members, you will create a strong reference cycle between the closure and the instance. Swift uses *capture lists* to break these strong reference cycles. For more information, see [Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56).

You don't have a strong reference cycle here but it is mentioned that the closure captures the instance, and that's what happens in your case. To prevent that you can explicitly capture it weakly:

```
func doSomething2() {
    someFunctionWithEscapingClosure { [weak self] in
        self?.x = 77
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `{ [unowned self] in
        self.x = 77
    }` instead?

Comment: ok I just thought that @escaping automatically create all weak links on  environment. You answer cleared my brain

Comment: @ВадимКамышников cool! I thought you knew something and went to double-check :-D

Comment: @AhmadF that would crash — a good evidence of `self` being `nil` by then.